# how to fetch parent and child table data which has many relations inside it in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables,  **Main** and **child** the image shown is the structure of it. 
I want to fetch the whole record detail in single query, ie, if the *HWType* column in main table is 3( this is the ID field from child table) ,I need to show the value corresponding to the ID from child table like wise if the *ProdModel* is 4 then the value corresponding to 4 from child table.

How can I achieve it in a single query.[image: Table structure]

Comment: Join child multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Serg said, join the main table with Child table as many times as needed.

```
select M.id, c1.Value HW, c2.Value Prod, c3.Value CD, c4.Value AV, c5.Value Comp
  from Main M 
       left join Child c1 on M.HWType = c1.ID
       left join Child c2 on M.ProductModel = c2.ID
       left join Child c3 on M.CDType = c3.ID
       left join Child c4 on M.AntivirusType = c4.ID
       left join Child c5 on M.Company = c5.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

someting like this :

```
select m.ID, m.HWType, m.ProductModel,  
       c.Value,  
       p.SomeField   
from   Main m  
  left outer join Child c on m.HWType = c.ID  
  left outer join Product p on m.ProductModel = p.ID
```

and so on...